# IdentityServer4 Handling Logout Correctly

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a IndentityServer4 project which handles the login functionality and a seperate MVCClient,  I need there to be a logout function from the MVC client however looking at the sames one simply has this (MVC client):

```
public async Task Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("oidc");
    }
```

but in the identityserver4 project there is a more complex logout which seems to do a lot more:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutViewModel model)
    {
        var vm = await _account.BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);
        if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
        {
            string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });
            try
            {
                // hack: try/catch to handle social providers that throw
                await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme,
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url });
            }
            catch (NotSupportedException) // this is for the external providers that don't have signout
            {
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException) // this is for Windows/Negotiate
            {
            }
        }

        // delete authentication cookie
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

        return View("LoggedOut", vm);
    }
```

Can someone explain the logic what is really required on the client.

Answer (score 1):

The first Logout method is used in the MVC client.
The second code belongs to the IdentityServer service.

The first Logout initializes some state for the logout process and redirects to the Logout view on IdentityServer (if you look at the samples there are two Logouts in the IdentityServer AccountController code: one for the logout verification view and one POST handler).